# How do I write a correct answer to Weibel exercise 1.1.1.?

Tags: proof-verification, modules, homological-algebra

Exercise 1.1.1.  Set $C_n = \Bbb{Z}/8$ for $n \geq 0$ and $C_n = 0$ for $n \lt 0$.  Let $d_n : x \pmod{8} \to 4x \pmod{8}$  Compute the homology modules of the chain complex $C_{\cdot}$.

I got that $\ker d_n = \{0,2,4,6\}$ for $n \gt 0$, $
\ker d_n = \Bbb{Z}/8$ for $n = 0$ and $\ker d_n = 0$ for $n \lt 0$.

I also got that $\text{im } d_{n+1} = \{0, 4\}$ for $n \gt 0$, and $\text{im } d_{n+1} = 0$ for $n \leq 0$.

So the homology modules are $\ker d_n / \text{im } d_{n+1} = \{\bar{0}, \bar{2}\} \approx \Bbb{Z}/2$ for $n \gt 0$, $(\Bbb{Z}/8) / 0 \approx \Bbb{Z}/8$ for $n = 0$ and $0/0 \approx 0$ for $n \lt 0$.  Did I do that right?  Also do I now say "the homology modules are $\Bbb{Z}/2$, etc." or that they're isomorphic to these?

Comment: Your computations seem completely correct. The correct thing would be to say that they are isomorphic to these groups.

Comment: That is the case, since $C_{-1} = 0$.

Comment: For $n=0$, im $d_{n+1}$  = $\frac{4\mathbb{Z}}{8\mathbb{Z}}$. So '$0^{th}$' homology module will be $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{4\mathbb{Z}}$. Other than this, everything is correct.